# Moving messageSource to applicationContext causes the default messageSource not to be visible in dispatcher-servlet context

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a webapp in which I define the basic `dispatcher-servlet` context in web.xml and it loads the `applicationContext`.

I had `messageSource` defined in `dispatcher-servlet` and was injecting it to controllers fine.

I also have my services defined in `applicationContext` and I can inject them into my controllers (defined in `dispatcher-servlet` context).

But when I moved my definition for `messageSource` to the `applicationContext` so that some services could resolve messages the `dispatcher-servlet` context shows that it's not finding a `messageSource` bean and is using the default, thus the controllers get the wrong bean injected.

Any idea why the messageSource definition in `applicationContext` wouldn't be visible to the `dispatcher-servlet` context?

---

I see that my messageSource bean is loaded in the `applicationContext` section of the logs:

```
2058 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'messageSource'
2058 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory  - Creating instance of bean 'messageSource'
...
2082 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Using MessageSource [mycommons.spring.ResourceBundleMessageSourceWithDefaultResolution: basenames=[messages]]
```

I see this log in the loading of `dispatcher-servlet`:

```
3858 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext  - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@55611ed3]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is just the way it works. The `messageSource` bean *must* be defined in the context in which it is to be used. It will not be "inherited" from parent context to child.

This is a bit of a throwback to the early days of Spring 1.x, and has never really been changed since.

There are a number of "magic beans" that must be resident directly in the servlet appcontext, and this is one of them.

Comment: Aha, that spring magic gets me sometimes. :)  Thanks! Do you know the best workaround? Or do I just need to separate messages that will be used by controllers from those that may be used by services?

Comment: @David: You can either separate them, or put the `messageSource` bean definition into a separate XML file, and include it (using `<import resource="...">`) wherever it's needed.

Comment: I assume that adding the <import resource="..."> to both dispatcher-servlet and applicationContext will create two copies of the messageSource bean.

Comment: @David Yes, it will. That should be harmless enough, though.

Comment: you can retrieve the parent messageSource in the childContext by calling `delegatingMessageSource.getParentMessageSource()`

Answer (score 1):

Today I found "another" solution that works (for me it works in Spring 3.1 but I assume it will work in earlier versions as well, the parent attribute has been around for a while now). It will still create 2 beans, but not require you to add the whole bean definition a second time in the xxx-servlet.xml file:

In your applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="baseMessageSource" class="org.springframework...YourMessageSourceClass">
   ...
</bean>
```

In your xxx-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource" parent="baseMessageSource" />
```

The second reference will simply "clone" the base bean from your application context and make it available to your servlet/controllers etc. This  way, you can even override parts of your message source configuration in the servlet.