# No qualifying bean ... spring-webmvc: bean defined in applicationContext is not visible in ServletContext

Tags: spring-mvc, applicationcontext, servletcontextlistener

I have problems with beans defined in APplicationContext. (May be my problems is understanding of Application~Servlet contexts ?)

So, I define **< bean id="messageSource"** in :

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.
<!-- // configure manage of transactions using annotations @Transactional // -->

<tx:annotation-driven />

<!-- // SPRING-SECURITY // -->
<import resource="security-servlet.xml" />

<!-- // DB1 - Database Configuration // -->
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring/db.config/jdbc-db1.properties" />

<import resource="./db.config/DataSource-db1.xml" />
<import resource="./db.config/jpa-config-db1.xml" />

<!-- Auto scan the components -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- // common beans for rest & mvc // -->
<context:component-scan base-package="abc.def.data"  />

<bean
    id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
>
    <property
        name="basename"
        value="validation" />
</bean>
```

also I have mvc-servlet.xml defines in web.xml as :

```
    <!-- // MVC // -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my @controller I use bean messageSource such way :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/su" )
public class AdminSuController {
private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger( getClass() );
    .....
    @Autowired
    private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
```

WHEN I define bean in mvc-servlet.xml - no problems 
as soon as I move it to (as I understand root context for servletContext) ApplicationContext.xml (I do that to use this beans in REST-servlet.xml and other @controller-s ) I get :

```
#19:41:26.594 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
```

> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'addressController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory .BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource
>   abc.def.rest.controller.AddressController.messageSource; nested
>   exception is org.sp
>   ringframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource]
>   found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which  qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE ]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>   ~[spring-context-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>   [servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1245)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1895)
>   [catalina.jar:7.0.59]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   [na:1.7.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>   [na:1.7.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>   [na:1.7.0]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>   [na:1.7.0]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0] Caused
>   by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource
>   abc.def.rest.controller.AddressControll er.messageSource; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource]
>   found for  dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELE ASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE ]  ... 34 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource]
>   found for dependency: expected at le ast 1 bean which qualifies as
>   autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1308)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELE ASE]  ... 36 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166244/moving-messagesource-to-applicationcontext-causes-the-default-messagesource-not

Comment: did you use contextloaderlistener in web.xml also?

Comment: Yes, of course.
The problem and SOLUTION is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166244/moving-messagesource-to-applicationcontext-causes-the-default-messagesource-not

Answer (score 1):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2843242/oerlien 
here is answer [Moving messageSource to applicationContext causes the default messageSource not to be visible in dispatcher-servlet context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166244/moving-messagesource-to-applicationcontext-causes-the-default-messagesource-not)

```
In your applicationContext.xml:

<bean id="baseMessageSource" class="org.springframework...YourMessageSourceClass">
   ...
</bean>

In your xxx-servlet.xml:

<bean id="messageSource" parent="baseMessageSource" />
```